# работа с файлами на c++

Tags: c++

по задумке я хотел чтобы было 4 файла

- world.cpp ( файл в котором код )
- world.txt ( файл где написана версия ( пример 0 ) )
- real_world.cpp ( файл с обновленым кодом )
- real_world.txt ( файл с версией ( пример 1 ) )

я хотел так чтобы файл world .txt и real_world . txt считывались в них хранится версия программы. 
если текст файлов не тот же что и в другом тогда программа брала код из real_world . cpp и загружала его в world.cpp

```
    // update.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". 

    #include "pch.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    string fille;   // название файла
    string version; // текушая версия файла

    string updates; // файл с обновлением
    string upVersion; // версия файла с обновлением

    void filles()
    {
        cout << "Введите название файла/программы" << endl;
        cin >> fille;

        cout << "Введите версию файла/программы" << endl;
        cin >> version;

        cout << "Введите файл с обновлением файла/программы" << endl;
        cin >> updates;

        cout << "Введите версию файла/программы с обновлением" << endl;
        cin >> upVersion;
    }

    void update()
    {
        char update[50];
        ifstream ifs(version);  // version
        ifs >> update;

        ifs.getline(update, 50);
        ifs.close();
        cout << "текушая версия файла: " << update << endl;
        string def_version = update;

        update[50];
        ifstream ifst(upVersion); // upVersion
        ifst >> update;

        ifst.getline(update, 50);
        ifst.close();
        cout << "версия файла с обновлением: " << update << endl;
        string up_version = update;

        if (def_version != up_version)
        {
            ifstream ifs(updates); // update
            ifs >> update;

            ifs.getline(update, 50);
            ifs.close();
            cout << "Код: " << update << endl;

            ofstream ofs(fille);
            ofs.open(fille);
            ofs << update << endl;
            ofs.close();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

        filles();
        if(version != upVersion) update();

        return 0;
    }
```

получается не то что нужно, он толи не может считать текст и код или я рукажопый

```
Введите название файла/программы 
world.cpp 

Введите версию файла/программы 
world.txt 

Введите файл с обновлением файла/программы 
real_world.cpp 

Введите версию файла/программы с обновлением 
real_world.txt 

текушая версия файла: 
версия файла с обновлением:
```

он не может проверить или считать файл.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Можете объяснить: на кой черт вы дважды считывание в массив char сначала через оператор >>, потом через getline и присваивание этот массив строке?

Comment: Не меняйте текст существующего вопроса -- задайте новый.

Comment: Надо проверять, что файл открылся и что чтение завершилось успехом.